# How do I make svg path hover area bigger

Tags: css, svg

**What I have:**

```css
#poly-1:hover {
    stroke: green;
}
```

```html
<svg width="1000" height="500" id="chart-main-canvas" style="background-color: bisque; z-index:5000;"> 
    <path id="poly-1" d="M 5,10 C 24,88 60.99999999999998,322 100,400 C 139,478 149,470 200,400 C 251,330 295,30.000000000000007 355,50 C 415,70 470.99999999999994,410 500,500" fill="none" stroke="red" style="z-index:6000;"></path>
</svg>
```

If I hover exactly on `path`, which is a tricky task, line it will change color to green.

**What I want to do** is to make hover area of this path bigger, so I could move my cursor somewhere `+-5px` near the `path` area and it will still change color.

The only two ways I know I could do is:

1. Make `stroke-width` bigger,  but I don't want its actual size with red color to increade.
2. With my main path create invisible duplicating path that has bigger `stroke-width` and add condition that if I hover on it - my main path will change color.

But there is any simple way to do it?

Comment: I'd go with option 2. Why do you think that's difficult?

Comment: @RobertLongson I am new in this drawing stuff and just wanted to ask do I make things complicated or not

Comment: Try this: `<svg width="1000" height="500" id="chart-main-canvas" style="background-color: bisque; z-index:5000;">
<defs><path id="poly-1" d="M 5,10 C 24,88 61,322 100,400 C 139,478 149,470 200,400 C 251,330 295,30 355,50 C 415,70 471,410 500,500" fill="none" ></path></defs>
  <g id="group">
  <use xlink:href="#poly-1" stroke-width="10" pointer-events="stroke"/>
  <use class="use" xlink:href="#poly-1" />
  </g>
</svg>` with this CSS: `#group .use{stroke:red}
#group:hover .use{
    stroke: green;
}`

Comment: @enxaneta I presumed that this way is the simplest, you just accepted my assumption. I will leave it as an answer if you write it below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is practically your second option.

I'm putting the path `#poly-1` in the defs and use it first with a wide stroke-width and no stroke. In order to make it sensitive to the mouse I'm using `pointer-events="stroke"`

```
<use xlink:href="#poly-1" stroke-width="10" pointer-events="stroke"/>
```

Next comes another use - the visible one - with a red stroke.

I'm putting both use elements in a group. The stroke of the second use element changes when I'm mousing over the group.

```css
#group .use {
  stroke: red
}

#group:hover .use {
  stroke: green;
}
```

```html
<svg width="1000" height="500" id="chart-main-canvas" style="background-color: bisque; z-index:5000;">
  <defs>
    <path id="poly-1" d="M 5,10 C 24,88 61,322 100,400 C 139,478 149,470 200,400 C 251,330 295,30 355,50 C 415,70 471,410 500,500" fill="none" >
    </path>
  </defs>
  <g id="group">
    <use xlink:href="#poly-1" stroke-width="10" pointer-events="stroke"/>
    <use class="use" xlink:href="#poly-1" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank! great idea with a wide string and `pointer-events="stroke"`

Answer (score 0):

I added stroke width for color change to highlight.
please try this..

```css
#poly-1:hover {
    stroke: green !important;
    stroke-width:2px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="1000" height="500" id="chart-main-canvas" style="background-color: bisque; z-index:5000;"> 
    <path id="poly-1" d="M 5,10 C 24,88 60.99999999999998,322 100,400 C 139,478 149,470 200,400 C 251,330 295,30.000000000000007 355,50 C 415,70 470.99999999999994,410 500,500" fill="none" stroke="red" style="z-index:6000;"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: That is not what I want to do. I want area that now in this code is green be a hover area, so I can easily get it by my mouse overlap and `path` should just change color to green, without changing its size

Comment: I see your edit now, but I still need to hover on this small `2px` area

Comment: remove stroke-width:2px;

Comment: I cannot remove it in your code now. And if I remove it nothing changes from my starting point in question.

Comment: !important used in stroke: green !important; that will change color to green when hover th path

Comment: I just add stroke-width for color change to be undertstand

Comment: If I just wanted to encreate its width I'd do it by myself, that is not an answer on my question `But there is any simple way to do it?`