# Code generated by javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, svg

I stucked a little.

I have a code that [is working in codepen](https://codepen.io/AlexeyVolosnikov/pen/zYqxRON) and if I paste it in opened F12 window it will work fine, so it is ok.

The idea of this svg code was that I can hover not exactly on `path`, but somewhere near, for it to change color.

But I need to generate exact same code using javascipt, I wrote 2 classes, used them, they now generate same code as in codepen link, I can see it in F12 dev window, but it doesn't work.

My javascript code:

```
class Polyline {

    // https://codepen.io/francoisromain/pen/dzoZZj
    
    constructor(points, smoothing, fill, color) {
        this.points = points;
        this.smoothing = (smoothing === undefined) ? 0.2 : smoothing;
        this.fill = fill;
        this.color = color;
    }

    line (pointA, pointB) {
        const lengthX = pointB[0] - pointA[0];
        const lengthY = pointB[1] - pointA[1];
        return {
            length: Math.sqrt(Math.pow(lengthX, 2) + Math.pow(lengthY, 2)),
            angle: Math.atan2(lengthY, lengthX)
        }
    }

    controlPoint (current, previous, next, reverse) {
        const p = previous || current;
        const n = next || current;
        const o = this.line(p, n);
        const angle = o.angle + (reverse ? Math.PI : 0);
        const length = o.length * this.smoothing;
      
        const x = current[0] + Math.cos(angle) * length;
        const y = current[1] + Math.sin(angle) * length;
        return [x, y];
    }

    bezierCommand(point, i, a) {
        const cps = this.controlPoint(a[i - 1], a[i - 2], point);
        const cpe = this.controlPoint(point, a[i - 1], a[i + 1], true);
        return `C ${cps[0]},${cps[1]} ${cpe[0]},${cpe[1]} ${point[0]},${point[1]}`;
    }

    svgPath(points, svg) {
        const d = points.reduce((acc, point, i, a) => i === 0
          ? `M ${point[0]},${point[1]}`
          : `${acc} ${this.bezierCommand(point, i, a)}`
        , '');
        
        const defs = document.createElement( 'defs' );
        defs.innerHTML = "<path id='poly-1' d='" + d + "' fill=" + this.fill + "></path>";

        svg.appendChild(defs);

        const g = document.createElement( 'g' );
        g.setAttribute("id", "group");
        svg.appendChild(g);

        const use1 = document.createElement( 'use' );
        use1.setAttribute("xlink:href", "#poly-1");
        use1.setAttribute("stroke-width", "15");
        use1.setAttribute("pointer-events", "stroke");
        g.appendChild(use1);

        const use2 = document.createElement( 'use' );
        use2.setAttribute("class", "use");
        use2.setAttribute("xlink:href", "#poly-1");
        g.appendChild(use2);

    }

    draw() {
        const svg = document.getElementById("chart-main-canvas");
        this.svgPath(this.points, svg);
    }

}


class Canvas {
    
    constructor(w, h, color) {
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
        this.color = color;
        // this.scale = 1;
    }

    canvas() {
        return `<svg width="${this.width}" height="${this.height}" id="chart-main-canvas"  style="background-color: ${this.color}; z-index:5000;" ></svg>`;
    }

    draw() {
        const c = document.getElementById("lifespan-chart-content");
        c.innerHTML = this.canvas();
    }

}


window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    c1 = new Canvas(1000, 500, "bisque");
    c1.draw();

    var smoothing = 0.2;
    var fill = "green";
    var color = "red";

    const points = [
        [5, 10],
        [100, 400],
        [200, 400],
        [355, 50],
        [500, 500]
    ]

    p1 = new Polyline(points, smoothing, fill, color);
    p1.draw();

});
```

Why and how I can fix it?

Another additional link on working svg example:[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63298635/how-do-i-make-svg-path-hover-area-bigger)

PS I pretty sure that the problem method is `svgPath` in `Polyline` class

**edit 1**

edited function:

```
    svgPath(points, svg) {
        const d = points.reduce((acc, point, i, a) => i === 0
        ? `M ${point[0]},${point[1]}`
        : `${acc} ${this.bezierCommand(point, i, a)}`
        , '');

        const defs = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'defs' );
        defs.innerHTML = "<path id='poly-1' d='" + d + "' fill=" + this.fill + "></path>";

        svg.appendChild(defs);

        const g = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'g' );
        g.setAttribute("id", "group");
        svg.appendChild(g);

        const use1 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",'use' );
        use1.setAttribute("xlink:href", "#poly-1");
        use1.setAttribute("stroke-width", "15");
        use1.setAttribute("pointer-events", "stroke");
        g.appendChild(use1);

        const use2 = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'use' );
        use2.setAttribute("class", "use");
        use2.setAttribute("xlink:href", "#poly-1");
        g.appendChild(use2);

    }
```

still doesnt work

Comment: Please read about [document.createElementNS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=document.createElementNS)

Comment: @enxaneta I have read the article. Changed `div` on `vbox` and `createElement` on `createElementNS("127.0.0.1:5500" ,...)`, but nothing have changed

Comment: Try `document.createElementNS( "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'whatever');`

Comment: @enxaneta now I have `const defs = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'defs' );` ... , and nothing changes. I probably need somehow to refresh block which is containing this stuff? Because if I write same code by ctrl + c ctrl + v it will work

Comment: besides the defs you are creating also an svg element, a path, a group 2 use elements...

Comment: @enxaneta I wrote `...` instead of other lines, please see my edit 1 to see full edited `svgPath` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use this technique to draw SVG, because it is not that simple to just `innerHTML` them

```js
// Your SVG code (formed as you wish)
const svgFromJS = `<svg width="1000" height="500" id="chart-main-canvas" style="background-color: bisque; z-index:5000;">
  <defs>
    <path id="poly-1" d="M 5,10 C 24,88 60.99999999999998,322 100,400 C 139,478 149,470 200,400 C 251,330 295,30.000000000000007 355,50 C 415,70 470.99999999999994,410 500,500" fill="none"></path>
    </defs>
  <g id="group">
    <use xlink:href="#poly-1" stroke-width="15" pointer-events="stroke"></use>
    <use class="use" xlink:href="#poly-1"></use>
  </g>
</svg>`;

// Create a tmp container
const c = document.createElement('div');

// Add SVG to tmp container
c.innerHTML = '' + svgFromJS;

// Move childs of the SVG inside tmp container to target SVG at the body
Array.prototype.slice.call(c.childNodes[0].childNodes).forEach(function(el) { 
  document.getElementById('swgtodraw').appendChild(el);
});
```

```css
#group .use{
  stroke:red
} 
#group:hover .use{
  stroke: green; 
}
```

```html
<svg id="swgtodraw" width="1000" height="500" style="background-color: bisque; z-index:5000;"></svg>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. But why `it is not that simple to just innerHTML`? Is there any explanation to this?

Comment: Well, in general `innerHTML` property supports simple DOM manipulations, but to do more complex stuff it's better to use DOM methods: https://www.impressivewebs.com/10-essential-dom-methods-techniques-for-practical-javascript/